# argouml php code generation

Tags: php, uml, argouml

Hopefully a quickie...

I'd like to know how/where to alter the settings in argouml that is used in autocode generation.  Files created have extra things in that I don't need (some comments, some code like e.g. version checking flow control) and include staements where there is a connection between classes in the diagram. All that I will handle myself.

Further to that is the filename convetion which is currently class.CLASSNAME.php which I'd like to swtch to lowercase classname .cls.php.

Finally - strugg;ong to get the relationships being output in ocde correctly - can't get a class to implement an interface nor extend a parent class.

Any tips gratefully received...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the bad news is that those options are compiled into the source. The good news is that you can modify the [source](http://argouml-php.tigris.org/source/browse/argouml-php/trunk/src/org/argouml/language/php/generator/GeneratorPHP4.java?revision=204&view=markup)! Unfortunately, there really isn't much you can do to work on it beyond that.

ArgoUML is really great for what it is -- open source, PC UML constructing software. But, it has all of the faults related to that too. One of the modules was in such bad shape that I felt the only option was becoming a committer.

Comment: Thank you - I think I'll get involved - like you say - for what it is its pretty awesome so I think it deserves some love and attention.

Comment: @cwallenpoole - which module which was in such bad shape that you became a committer for it?   @Ian Wood - new contributors are always welcome (I've contributed for over 5 years), but I'd recommend focusing your attention on the template based solution if you need anything other than something quick and dirty.

Comment: @Tom Actionscript module would not even create the directory structure, let alone create runable scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off asking in one of the ArgoUML forums, where you'd be sure the question would be seen by the ArgoUML developers.

The current code generator has the boilerplate baked into the Java code.  There's been some work done on a [template-based generator](http://argoprint.tigris.org/) (not for PHP, but it'd be possible to retarget), but I'm not sure how far along it is.